# How can I check a received string for a specific word?

Tags: vb.net, arduino

I am sending the string "end" from my arduino uno to a vb.net application. I want the vb.net app to recognise the word and conduct a specific action. I can see that the word is being received in the console, but it doesn't seem to be recognised by the code.

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Console.WriteLine(SerialPort1.ReadExisting)
    If SerialPort1.ReadExisting IsNot "end" Then
        dataRxd = dataRxd & SerialPort1.ReadExisting
    Else
        txtRx.Text &= dataRxd
        Console.WriteLine("###############")
        Console.WriteLine(dataRxd)

        'Dim result As newData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of newData)(dataRxd)
        'Dim com As result.com

        'SerialPort1.Close()
        'MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        'MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=g4rg45m3ll1;database=tags"
        'Try
        '    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
        '    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
        '    Dim bSource As New BindingSource
        '    MySqlConn.Open()
        '    'Query = "update tags.tags_read set LastRead= now() where TagID='" & dataRxd & "';"
        '    Query = "insert into tags.tags_read values ('" & dataRxd & "', now());"
        '    cmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
        '    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        'Catch ex As MySqlException
        '    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        'End Try
        'MySqlConn.Dispose()
        'MySqlConn.Close()
        'SerialPort1.Open()
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is a sample of the received data to the vb.net app, showing that the word is being received:

0001220000570221001B
end
0001220000570221001B
end
The thread 0x4a70 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: There's nothing I hate more than inconsistency.  You have numerous method calls in the commented-out code where you have no parameters but still use parentheses.  Consistency requires that you do the same for `ReadExisting`.  Personally, I ALWAYS use parentheses when calling a method so that method calls are distinguished from getting properties.  The only place I don't use optional parentheses is on constructors, so that they aren't easily confused with arrays.  I would suggest to anyone else that they do the same.

Answer (score 1):

`ReadExisting` is a method, not a property.  If you call it once then you are reading the existing data, so there's no more data.  You can't call it again and get the same data.  If you expect to use the data that you read more than once then do as should always be the case: assign the method result to a variable and then use that variable as required.

```
Dim msg = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()

Console.WriteLine(msg)
If msg <> "end" Then
    dataRxd = dataRxd & msg
```

Note that I also used `<>` rather than `IsNot`, because it's really value equality and not reference equality that you care about.